# How does params[:id] not throw an exception even if we do not explicitly whitelist :id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

In rails 4.x, strong_parameters require parameters to be explicitly permitted. Yet, in the following example, I do NOT get a `ForbiddenAttributesError` - why does `:id` not throw when in the `show` action even though it is not explicitly permitted?

```
def FooController
  ...
  def show
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:id]) # why no exception here?
  end

  private
    def foo_params
      params.require(:foo).permit(:name, :address) # note: No :id here
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

"With strong parameters, Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted."

Doing a `find` is completely valid, and is, in fact, shown in the example in the documentation linked to, above.

Answer (score 3):

Strong parameters are used only for assignment of attributes. You can freely search and perform other operations with any param, just not mass assignment.

You can see more in-depth explanation and examples [in Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

For Rails, `params[:id]` outside from default params.

- Query string:
  `www.example.com/foo/123?bar=1&baz=2`
- Request path:
  `www.example.com/foo/123` where `123` is `params[:id]`
- Paramerts:
   `bar=1&baz=2` this can be permitted

If you pass `123` to parameters then you need permitted `:id`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of explicitly permitting the `:id` unless you want to.Rails will do it `implicitly`.If want to check whether the `:id` is whitelisted or not,you can do `puts params[:foo]` after it is created or you can just see the log.you will see something like this

```
{id=>some_id, "name"=>"some_name", "adddress"=>"some_address"}
```

So,defining a `Foo` object like this

```
@foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
```

will not throw an exception.

Hope it helped!